# How can I write a conditional validation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Let's say I have a model, Post.rb:

```
validates :title => true
validates :post => true, :length => { :maximum => 220 } 
validate :custom_validation

def custom_validation 
   ...
end
```

I want to run the validtions for title, post, and the custom_validation ONLY if another attribute, draft, is false. (ie ignore when draft is true).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
validates :title => true, :unless => :draft
```